# Select and show only parent node based on child selection

Tags: c#, linq, list

How have one nested list of hierarchies:

```
A--A1---A2
|        |
|        A21
|
B--B1---B2
|   |     |
|   B11  B21
|
C--C1---C2
|   |     |
|   C11  C21
```

Now my slection will be on Leaf node only i.e. B21 then only B-B2--B21- should be in my list.

```
B----B2
|     |
|    B21
|
```

How can i do it in smarter way or any function where I will pass any node nad its parent will appear.

Comment: You'll have to give us more detail about how your code is structured for us to be able to help you with this. It will totally depend on how you are storing and accessing these items.

Comment: You can simply look at the direct parent - if a node is the parent of the selected node, include it and so on - you can do this in a while loop to avoid recursion e.g. `while(node.Parent != null) { nodeList.Add(node.Parent); node = node.Parent; }`

Comment: @Mashton: the question has been updated to stop all those `-` and `|` collapsing into one mass. Hopefully a refresh should allay that concern...

Comment: (Removed `-` and `|` comment now things look pretty). How is your data structured in code OP? Does a node know its parent, its children, or both? Is B not a child of A? If so, why isn't that brought back in your example? It is shown with the same kind of relationship that B11 has to B1, for example.

Comment: A,B,C individual entries in list, each node has collection of children and each holds its Parent reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since [each node has a reference to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725942/select-and-show-only-parent-node-based-on-child-selection#comment40219315_25725942) getting a sequence of a node with all of its parents is quite trivial:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Ancestors<T>(T node, Func<T, T> parentSelector)
{
    T current = node;
    while(current != null)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = parentSelector(current);
    }
}
```

You can then pass in a node and a function indicating how to get its parent:

```
var Ancestors = Ancestors(node, n => n.Parent);
```